# Automatic Teams meeting invites with Apple Calendar

Tags: ical, exchange

I really don’t get on with Outlook, and have configured Apple Mail and Calendar to access my company’s Exchange account. This works perfectly apart from one thing: Outlook (or Teams) will automatically generate Teams online meeting links attached to an event, but if I create it in Apple Calendar I don’t get that.

Is there any way to configure Calendar (or the Exchange backend) to do this when Calender creates an event?

My workaround at the moment is to use Teams calendar to create events, and Apple Calendar for everything else. But that’s a bit painful.

Comment: The old saw about apples and oranges applies here. I believe you just need to use Outlook, as painful as that may be. I've done a little Google searching, and tried to help my wife with a similar problem, with no luck.

Comment: The best you can do is copy a link from the Teams calendar and put it in your Apple Calendar.app manually. I've been dealing this for a while and besides my opinion on Teams as a steaming pile of... ahem... Teams is Microsofts way of locking you into their whole Microsoft-Only environment, so the only integration they are likely to provide is via the clipboard.

Comment: I think this might be the relevant feature request? https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/35166211-integrate-with-apple

Answer (score 7):

Whoever still in need for a solution

I used MS Power Automate to fix the issue

1. Create Meeting in Apple Calendar App

[image: MEETING IN APPLE CALENDAR APP]

2. Trigger Power Automate - I used location "TEAMS" as condition to do the magic.

[image: Power Automate to create Meeting link etc.]

... then wait or refresh calendar. The meeting is been replaced and includes the MS Teams link etc. Now you may invite people as desired.

Comment: What is Power Automate and how can it be installed on macOS?

Comment: @nohillside Power Automate is a website used to automate various functions, mostly relating to Microsoft accounts. Check out https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/ for more info.

Comment: Your answer might benefit from some details on how this works and how this can be used.

Comment: Assuming you have a O365/M365 account with your work email address, it pretty simple. Just go to flow. Microsoft.com login with your credentials and create an new flow. You may use my screenshot to get started. It‘s all there.  Select trigger (what triggers the automation) - for me it was the creation of a new event. Then add a condition that devides OTHER events from the ones you‘d like to create teams meetings for. In my example I said I‘d like to run it for all meetings that have location = TEAMS.

Comment: Next action should be to create a teams meeting. Fill in all fields as desired (fix values or dynamic content). 
Next action is to delete your trigger event (which we replaced before with the teams meeting)

Comment: @MartinWölzmüller, thanks a ton for posting this! I never tinkered with PowerAutomate, but it turns it's really powerful! I played around with it a bit more and I was able to come up with another (perhaps smoother) solution, will be posting it here as a separate answer.

Comment: Just saw your response and tested in. Unfortunately: “You are not permitted to make flows in this [organisation name]”  Still, glad it’s working for other people!

Answer (score 2):

The best I currently have is:

1. Create everything in Calendar App (time, name, description, participants, etc.)
2. Go to Teams and edit the meeting - e.g. add space in description.

   Not the best, but it's something.
   Did you guys find any better option?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution, it's a bit more flexible than the one created by Martin above as it retains all information from the original meeting, and you don't have to create an artificial location for it (which means you can use the location field to actually reserve an office conference room, etc.).

The usage in iCal is very simple:

- create a meeting as usual – add attendees, conference room, etc.
- **add `*` to the end of the meeting's subject** – I used star symbol, but this is customisable, see below.
- wait, and let the magic happen ;)

---

Ok, let's go:

In Power Automate, **create an Automated cloud flow**

[image]

**In the modal** that appears, set flow name, and search for the trigger as shown below (choose the version applicable to your Outlook, for me it's V3)

[image]

**Flow builder page appears.** Make sure it looks like shown below, scroll down to see steps explained.

[image]

1. Pick the calendar that you're using
2. Add the condition that checks if the meeting subject ends with the star symbol. As you can see, uou can configure this to be any unique symbol, such as #, @, or whatever. To me, a star felt simple and unobtrusive.
3. ("If yes" section) Create an action **which will create a new Teams meeting**, using data from our iCal event (subject, body, time zone, start/end times).
4. Create an action which **will update our iCal event**, using all the original data we provided BUT ALSO it will add the Teams link, taking it from  the Teams meeting created in step 3. It's referring to the Teams meeting via the "joinUrl" attribute.
5. Create an action which **will delete the Teams meeting** created in step 3, since we don't need it anymore. It's referring to the meeting via the "id" attribute.

---

When you click on any field in the flow builder, it will allow you to pick attributes ("dynamic content") from the list. You will find all the Outlook-related ones which are shown on the image, as well as the Teams-related ones. The list is long so make sure you scroll down or use the filter:

[image]

---

That's it, now just create an event in iCal, wait a bit, and there you go!

Comment: This worked a treat! thanks so much for taking the time to document this (:

Comment: @Dom sure thing, glad you liked it!

Answer (score 0):

There is no authentication plug in I’ve seen to generate the new teams invite. You could copy an existing meeting link for a team and copy/paste that when scheduling.

For me and people in our organization like you, we recommend using the web app for teams in Firefox or Edge browser to book all teams meetings using the calendar view at https://teams.microsoft.com and let the calendar do it’s thing syncing. You might also want to check out two third party native calendar apps. Both are superb value and offer amazing features.

- https://www.busymac.com/busycal
- https://flexibits.com/fantastical

Answer (score -2):

I avoid Outlook and set up meetings in Teams; works okay if you really hate engaging with Outlook.

If your Apple Calendar is synced with your Outlook Calendar (through Exchange or whatever), it'll appear in your Apple Calendar automatically.

It'll also appear in your Outlook calendar, useful for colleagues who might want to stalk you there.